# Mink selectors: any way to get the element in base of the content inside?

Tags: symfony, bdd

for example, given the text of a link, retrieve the hole link element.

I tried this:

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$page->find('content', 'Italiano');
```

But it says:

> Selector "content" is not registered.

**EDIT**: after check the links of the everzet's answers I have this:

```
$el = $page->find('named', array(
        'content', $this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getSelectorsHandler()->xpathLiteral('Pound')));

$el->click();
```

but I'm getting this error about `click()` function:

> ```
> When I choose "Pound sterling" #
> ```
>
> MyFirm\FrontendBundle\Features\Context\CurrencyControllerContext::iChoose()
>
> error:_click(_byXPath("(//html/./descendant-or-self::*[contains(normalize-space(.),
>   'Pound')])[1]"))
>         TypeError: parent.tagName is undefined
>         ([object
>   HTMLHtmlElement],"A",1)@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:3286
>         ([object
>   HTMLHtmlElement],"A")@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:3762
>         ([object
>   HTMLHtmlElement])@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:331
>         ([object HTMLHtmlElement],false,false,(void
>   0))@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:708
>         ([object
>   HTMLHtmlElement])@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:478
>         ()@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:3016
>         ()@http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:3016
>         @http://myfirm.localhost/*s*/spr/concat.js:2822
>
> ```
>   <a
> ```
>
> href='/*s*/dyn/Log_getBrowserScript?href=null&n=3286'>**Click for
>   browser script**

This is the beginning of the output of `var_dump($el)`:

```
object(Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement)#438 (2) {
  ["xpath":"Behat\Mink\Element\NodeElement":private]=>
  string(74) "(//html/./descendant-or-self::*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'Pound')])[1]"
```

And the output of `$el->getTagName()` is 'html'.

Is that because I'm trying to click something that is not an element but just content? In that case, any way to get the element from the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use content selector. Because in almost any case it will provide results, that you don't expect. For example, when you're doing `content(Pound)`, you're expecting that it'll return you an element, that contains this text. The reality is, every parent element of target one is containing your "Pound" text, including `<html/>`. That's why you get `<html/>` at the end ;-)

Minks selectors are well-explained in the manual:

- http://mink.behat.org

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$page->find('css', 'Italiano');
```

This is using the CSS selectors, and it works like a magic!
But make sure 'Italiano' refers to an element on the page (I would use '#Italiano' if it's an ID).

You can read the traversing pages documentation [here](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/traversing-pages.html).

Comment: I've updated this answer with the traversing pages documentation as it's the most useful answer so far.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jimbo